# Is it possible to stop execution in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Basically I want to be able to wrap any command in a $.holdTillFinished() method that will not allow execution to continue until the specified method/jquery animation is finished executing.

I suspect that this may be difficult or even impossible in javascript, but I'm hoping someone will know.

I don't want to hear about how I can pass a callback into an animation to have it run oncomplete, or anything else like that.

I really want to know if such a thing is possible and how to go about it.

If that isn't going to happen if anyone knows of a nice queue plugin that is capable of queuing both user defined methods and animations, that would be cool too.  What I really want is a way to delay execution though.(while still allowing animations to function)

Comment: @thirsty: You want queue and dequeue, I think (already suggested and dismissed by you below).  You can queue arbitrary methods along with animations and they will execute in order.  If this isn't what you are asking then could you clarify your question with an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have not seen a queue that works for functions.

What I mean is if I pass an animation, then a function, then an animation into the queue then while those animations are playing the function should not be executing.  Also I do not want to have to specify how long the function will take to execute.

Comment: But really what I want is a wrapper that stops all javascript until the function/animation I have passed into it has resolved

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I suspect that this may be difficult or even impossible in javascript

Your suspicion is correct. Methods like animations, user input loops and ‘async=true’ XMLHttpRequests *must* return control to the browser in order to proceed, and the browser can't get back control until every nesting level of function call has returned. That means all your code, including the function that called ‘holdTillFinished()’ would have to unwind: therefore ‘holdTillFinished()’ is impossible.

Other languages have flow-control features that allow you to effectively execute an asynchronous process as one that appears to the caller to be synchronous, and similarly vice-versa. The best-known are [threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computer_science)) and [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation). JavaScript does not possess these facilities, so the best you can do is timeouts and callbacks.

(Defining a callback as an inline function to gain access to the enclosing function's variables in a closure does at least take some of the pain out of it; some other languages have to start wrapping every bit of enclosing state in an object's properties to achieve this.)

Comment: Well pretty much all modern (non-browser) languages give you threads, using OS support. Continuations/coroutines can be found in at least Haskell, ML and Scheme and some extensions to other languages (eg. Stackless Python); there are primitives in C that can be used to build continuations.

Comment: Of course, in the browser world, you're stuck: apart from JavaScript there's only VBScript, and that's even worse! JavaScript 1.7 (in Firefox 2) gives you Python-style generators, which are a limited form of continuation that wouldn't really help you here.

Comment: Shoot, I actually meant "what languages have to start wrapping every bit of enclosing state in an object's properties to achieve this?".

Comment: Languages without first-class functions and closures, such as C[++] and Java. (Java's anonymous inline classes can almost do it, in that they can read but not write outer function variables.)

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/queue

But if you're looking for a more generalized way of delaying things, I've used this snippet before (I didn't write it, so all credit goes to the original author):

```
//Simple wrapper enabling setTimout within chained functions.
$.fn.wait = function(time, type) {
  time = time || 1000;
  type = type || "fx";
  return this.queue(type, function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(self).dequeue();
    }, time);
  });
};
```

Comment: This doesn't delay execution until the function ends.
What this does is delay execution in the queue by some time limit that I am setting.  I don't know how long it takes to run any given function and I shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: This is better then nothing though.  But it's really not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a publish/subscribe architecture to achieve what you want. Without knowing much about what exactly you want to achieve, my guess is this will work for you.

The way this works is that you look at the completion of function as an event, which you can listen to and attach handlers to. [Dojo has a pubsub mechanism](http://dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-3-programmatic-dijit-and-dojo/event-system/publish-and-subscribe-events), though I'm sure there are others.

Comment: This is exactly what I do not want.  A callback that I pass in to the function/animation in question

Answer (score 0):

It defends upon situation but normally it is necessary to show a processing image to be shown when AJAX is called or any loop is executing in javascript. I have a situation where I am calling AJAX in a loop, for the user to show the processing image is shown. To terminate I done a trick. I have put a button to cancel the job when this function is called I set a global variable say 'cancelJob' to true and in the loop where I am checking this global if this is true the run return false and the script will stop.

```
var cancelJob = false;
foreach(){
   if(cancelJob == true)
       return false;
}

function cancelButtonPress(){
   cancelJob = true;
}
```