# jQuery - How to animate click function without clicking (Slide-show like) - Is this possible?

Tags: jquery, automation, jquery-animate, slideshow

I have created a jQuery script (with help) that works great however I need it to automate/animate itself without using the click function, I just want to know is this possible and if so, how? Similar to a slide-show.

Basically the code allows me to click on an image and hide/show a DIV, while changing a list of elements such as class/id name.

Here's my code:

**JQUERY:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    //if this is not the first tab, hide it
    jQuery(".imgs:not(:first)").hide();
    //to fix u know who
    jQuery(".imgs:first").show();
    //when we click one of the tabs
    jQuery(".img_selection a").click(function(){
        //get the ID of the element we need to show
        stringref = jQuery(this).attr("href").split('#')[1];

        // adjust css on tabs to show active tab
        $('.img_selection a').removeAttr('id'); // remove all ids
        $(this).attr('id', this.className + "_on") // create class+_on as this id.
        //hide the tabs that doesn't match the ID
        jQuery('.imgs:not(#'+stringref+')').hide();
        //fix
        if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substr(0,3) == "6.0") {
            jQuery('.imgs#' + stringref).show();
        } else
            //display our tab fading it in
            jQuery('.imgs#' + stringref).show();
        //stay with me
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I quite don't get what is your problem here... If you want to call it automatically, just call it on document ready or using setTimeout ?

Comment: I'm new at all of this so I'm not really sure how to do that, anymore insight? I'd love the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. It gets all "tabs" and clicks im in circular order with a pause of 2 seconds (2000ms) between each click

```
var tabs = jQuery(".img_selection a");
var len = tabs.size();
var index = 1;
function automate() {
    tabs.eq((index%len)).trigger('click');
    index++;
}
var robot = setInterval(automate, 2000);

//if at some point you want to stop the automation just call
clearInterval(robot);
```

Made a demo

[http://jsbin.com/urulo/2/](http://jsbin.com/urulo/2) (http://jsbin.com/urulo/2/edit for the code)

Comment: @jitter: I added this to my code but it doesn't work, I could be placing it in the wrong spot. Any ideas?  Sorry I'm definitely a beginner with jquery/js.

Comment: Check link in expanded answer. Made a demo for you and optimized your code a bit too

Comment: This works great man, but I only see one issue. Since it loads on tab1, then the animation starts on tab1, so it loads that one twice. Is there a way to have the animate start on tab2 ?  so on page load it loads 1, then it animates to tab 2?

Comment: Also, how can I stop the animation when I click on one of the tabs? Is that possible?

Sorry for the all the questions, I've tried a bunch of things but they don't work, so I'm asking. :)  thank you for all the help though, its greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the first question. Just change `var index=0;` to `var index=1;`

Comment: For the second question. I already had the needed line inside the code (of course commented out). Check the changed answer (provided new links for adapted demo)

Comment: I figured out index = 1, thank you for that, I'm looking at the code now to stop it. I'm learning so much by this website and everyone, so I really do appreciate it

Comment: @jitter: by adding clearInterval(robot); to the top part after (".imgs").hide().. it doesn't stop when I click on the tabs, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

> [Time-limiting a function execution is not possible in Javascript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680021/is-it-possible-to-stop-execution-in-javascript-jquery)

But, HTML5 brings along web-workers, which are basically background *worker* threads. It is possible to [*suspend*](http://svn.whatwg.org/webworkers/index#processing-model) a web-worker after a certain time.