# Can I stop JavaScript function execution via global variables?

Tags: javascript

So I read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680021/is-it-possible-to-stop-execution-in-javascript-jquery) a bit, and it looks like JavaScript functions can't be explicitly killed off mid-run. What if I have a global variable, `window.currentlyProcessing` that manages this.

```
function contentsChanged()
{
    if( window.curentlyProcessing == true )
    {
        return;
    }
    window.curentlyProcessing = true;
    // DO STUFF
    window.curentlyProcessing = false;
}
```

Since `contentsChanged` gets called a lot, will this effectively stop it from running over itself?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having that is causing you to try and do this?  Why is `contentsChanged` getting called so often?

Comment: @cwolves - it gets called on EVERY keystroke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript is single threaded - one function is executed at a time, the function will never "run over itself" to begin with. `contentsChanged` will get called, will execute until the end, then any other stuff will happen.

Comment: Well, that is not really correct (http://bradkellett.com/p/javascript-worker-threads/), Though I am not exactly sure if this is saying that you have to be worried about concurrency at all or not.

Comment: @Jonathon Yes, but you need to explicitly use web workers, and if you did you wouldn't be asking this question. Forgive me for keeping the answer simple.

Answer (score 0):

That would prevent the logic from running if it's already running. If that's what you need to do, it should work.